# How to enable custom "low power mode" on a mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

The low power mode on MacBook settings apparently might decrease refresh rate of the display and power consumption of the processor.

Is there an app providing the option to do this in a customisable way, for instance keeping the display settings unchanged, and only make changes related to the processor?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297330

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force "low power mode" on mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297330/force-low-power-mode-on-mac)

Comment: This is not a dupe. This questions asks if there is a way to *customize* low power settings while the other asks how to turn it on.